# Integrating when using density function estimated

Tags: r

i'm trying to integrate a density function but I'm getting the error

```
Error in integrate(approxfun(data_density), lower = strike_x, upper = strike_y) : 
  non-finite function value
```

I removed NAs from data_density already
This is my code

```
data_density <- density(na.omit(data$AAPL.Close))

prob<-try(integrate(approxfun(data_density), lower=strike_x, upper=strike_y))
```

strike_x and strike_y are positive integers
How can I fix this?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: +1 For @MrFlick.  From what you've given us so far, I don't think your problem is `NA`s.  I think `approxfun` is returning `Inf` for some values of `datadensity`.